# Open Source ALM

Tags: open-source, alm

I am looking for the current recommendations for all-inclusive open source ALM system, essentially an open source alternative to Microsoft's Team Foundation Server.

I have found two so far, Jabox and Endeavour.

Are there any others that you know of?

If you have experience with Jabox or Endeavour, can you comment on their relative merits?

I am looking specifically for all-in-one ALM solutions like Jabox and Endeavour, rather than individual applications like Jenkins, Bugzilla, TestLink, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two popular ones are [OSEE](http://eclipse.org/osee/) from Eclipse.org and [Tuleap](http://www.tuleap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian family of products can be considered as a single product. As far as I know they are open source and Atlassian gives them for free if you are developing an open source solution.